# XLS to pdf converter - unexpected error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using SautinSoft.XlsToPdf.dll to convert xls to pdf. 
It works properly in console application, but thorws an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in web application and I don't know why.

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        byte[] pdfBytes = FromExcel(Server.MapPath("~/Doc/PlanningGame.xlsx"));
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;    filename=PlanningGame.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.Write(pdfBytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }


    public static byte[] FromExcel(string xlsFile)
    {
        XlsToPdf xtop = new SautinSoft.XlsToPdf();

        byte[] pdfBytes = null;
        xtop.ConvertBytes(File.ReadAllBytes(xlsFile), ref pdfBytes);//"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." 

        string tempFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", Config.TempDirectory, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        var bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.CreateNew));
        bw.Write(pdfBytes);
        bw.Close();

        return pdfBytes;

    }
```

File.ReadAllBytes(xlsFile) returns an array of bytes, so it's not null. xtop is not null too.

**UPDATE:**
The error throws if xlsFile locates in web application directory. If I use something like this

```
 byte[] pdfBytes = null;
 xtop.ConvertBytes(File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\ExcelSheet.xls"), ref pdfBytes);
```

an error doesn't throw.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Security? I'm guessing your server is prevented from accessing the directory containing the document.

---

**EDIT** First let's check my guess:

```
public static byte[] FromExcel(string xlsFile)
{
    XlsToPdf xtop = new SautinSoft.XlsToPdf();

    byte[] xlsBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(xlsFile);
    // is xlsBytes null? put a break-point here, or debug-print statement if you can't debug a running server.
    byte[] pdfBytes = null; 
    xtop.ConvertBytes(xlsBytes, ref pdfBytes);

    string tempFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", Config.TempDirectory, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    var bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.CreateNew));
    bw.Write(pdfBytes);
    bw.Close();

    return pdfBytes;

}
```

Comment: I don't know. How do I check and avoid it?

Comment: So the problem has to be that pdfBytes is null, yeah? So try `byte[] pdfBytes = new byte[1024*1024];` ... I'm just guessing here. I don't have any doco (or experience) on SautinSoft.XlsToPdf. I suspect XlsToPdf fills a "buffer", which must be a fixed-preasigned, so you have to GUESS how big it's got to be. Charming.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it's security problem.